# Android notification deleteIntent call function in IntentService

Tags: java, android, notifications, intentservice

## Hello!

I have a class that extends `IntentService`. It checks for new DB-entrys and displays a notification if a new entry is found, sleeps for a few seconds and repeats.
All already displayed ("notified") entrys are saved in a local "ignore list" and have the same notification-ID as they have in the DB.

#### Now my question:

When a notification is cancelled (i.e. the user either swipes it away or taps on "clear all"), I want to add the ID of the notification/the DB-entry to the "ignore list" so there does not come a new notification after a few seconds.
But I have no idea how to get the notification ID when reacting to the cancelling.
How do I get the properties (for example the ID, contentTitle, contentText an so on) of a `Notification` when using a deleteIntent?

## Edit:

Function to display notification:

```
private void showNotification(String title, String text, int icon, int notificationID) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    mBuilder.setContentText(text);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationDeleteReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", notificationID);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("text", text);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Reaction in the receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int id = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
    String title = intent.getExtras().getString("title");
    String text = intent.getExtras().getString("text");

    Log.v("qwerty", "Notification has been deleted!\nid: " + id + "\ntitle: " + title + "\ntext: " + text);
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but passively scanning for changed and sleeping is not Android way to do things. Better to just have a hook in DB modification code that sends the intent to your Intent Service

Comment: @f.khantsis How exactly would you do this? 
Could you give any code examples (MySQL database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourBrodcastReceiver.class);
      intent.putExtra("notificationId",notificationId)
      intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()))
      // pass all the value in intent
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this):
      builder.setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent); // this is delete intent it will call when you cancel or swipe
```

In `yourBrodcastReceiver` class is broadcast receiver where you can do that..

You can get notification id through

`int notificationId = intent.getExtras().getInt("notificationId");
//get all value in intent`

You can pass all data to intent service.. through intent

Comment: It does not work. No matter wich notification is deleted, the receiver always gets the data of the newest post. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Make sure you pass unique data to intent..like every time you need to initialize this `Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourBrodcastReceiver.class);
      intent.putExtra("notificationId",notificationId)` and also pending intent `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);` .Intent and Pending should be new for every notification.

Comment: Make sure .. every notification should have there uniqueid

Comment: All notifications have unique IDs. Now, always the oldest notification is displayed. I have added the actual code to the question.